# How to find the all LAN systems mode using c# whether the system is in log off or hibernate

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using ip address to find the active state of the machine

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping p = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply rep = p.Send(ip);
            if (rep.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here. Does the code you've shown work or not? If not, *how* is not working? What behavior do you see, and how does that compare to the results that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code to check the status..and also explore this site you could get some idea...[System.Net.NetworkInformation Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.aspx)

```
  using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
  public bool IsNetworkLikelyAvailable() 
  {
  return NetworkInterface
  .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
  .Any(x => x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);
    }
```